# Missing kannada (or asian) fonts with xvfb and firefox on ubuntu installed

Tags: firefox, encoding, utf-8, fonts, xvfb

Kannada(or asian) fonts were not encoded correctly in firefox which is run by xvfb and operating system is ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri
sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic
sudo apt-get install ttf-indic-fonts

By installing the fonts on the system solved the issue